# Crop HD (1920x1080) video ratio from the center in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, full-hd

I have an HD video (1920x1080). I am trying to crop the video from the center so the resolution is (960x1080) and looks like a portrait video. I have tried the following command with no luck:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -filter:v "crop=960:1080:480:0" -c:a copy out.mp4`

This just outputs a video at the same size: 1920x1080

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Share full log.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is doing fine, and ffprobe will show the resolution as **960x1080**

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:10:45.14, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1969 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 8:9], 1838 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

My suggestion is to go through some of the examples from https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop to see if you have any expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "crop=960:1080" out.mp4
```